# Check if a view function was called

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, unit-testing, testing

I'd like to test if my JS timer runs my timeout view:

```
    def testTimeLimit(self):
      self.client.get('/')
      response = self.client.get('/new',follow = True)
      sleep(2)
      #Assertion that checks if timeout view was called
```

How could I check what view functions were called in a session in chronological order? I know this test is easy to do in selenium but is it possible with a django.test.TestCase?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, since the test client is incapable of running Javascript. Perhaps someone more experienced will correct me, but I don't think you can test this at all just with Django, since that operates entirely on the server side and you're trying to test client side functionality.

Comment: Well yes but the question isn't specifically about JS I just want to check if you can display recently called view functions

Comment: you can by mocking view method